# How to wait for "all" promises when you keep adding more promises to the list?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, bluebird

Each promise is for a hit on a database.
I am doing a drill-down into a relational database.
Each select that returns something might trigger more selects that are required.

So...I have an unknown number of promises to wait for.
I am only really "finished" when all promises are done and there are no new ones added to the list.

My "db" object keeps an internal array of promises, and provides a "wait()" function to wait for all of them, but I never know when it's really done, so I end up doing this:

```
db.wait().then ->
    db.wait().then ->
        db.wait().then ->
            db.wait().then ->
                db.wait().then ->
                    console.log "finished waiting"
```

Which works, but only because I have a limited number of "levels".
( what if the number of "levels" was unlimited? )

Is there an existing pattern for accumulating promises where the handler might add more promises to the list?

Comment: You want recursion.